# Power BI: Top 5 clients Profit% chart wrong due to clients sharing multiple branches

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement to show Gross profit and GP% for the top 5 clients.
I have created the Gross profit bar chart for top 5 clients and its correct as expected. I have concatenated the client and branch columns in table Revenue and used that to get top 5 clients.

But for GP%, I have created the following measure.

```
% GP per Client = DIVIDE (    SUM ( Revenue[GrossProfit] ),    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Revenue[GrossProfit]), ALL ( DimClient[ClientName]) ))
```

I am unable to filter with branch and client concatenated and so getting wrong values. Snapshot of sample data, wrong chart and required correct chart below:
[image]

Here is the relationship between my tables:
[image]

Can anyone please let me know how I can achieve the correct values in GP%?

Regards

Comment: You mentioned "It should be only using 7141". Why? There is nothing in your report image that indicates this specific branch.

Comment: Hey RADO, SMARTCELL client is in two different branches so the top 5 would return the branch and client combined which would be 7141. Am I being clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by creating the following measure.

```
% GP per Client = DIVIDE (
SUM ( revenue[GrossProfit] ),
CALCULATE ( SUM ( revenue[GrossProfit]), ALL (revenue[Client And Branch])
```

))

Apply the filter on [client and branch] column for top 5.

My Issue was I was selecting all clients from clients table, I should have been selecting all clients and branch combined from the revenue table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below measure :

```
grossprofit total for clientid = 
CALCULATE(SUM('revenue'[grossprofit]), ALLSELECTED('revenue'[clientid]),ALLSELECTED('revenue'[branchid]))
```

Note : change the **Show Value as** option to **Percentage of Grand Total** in Values toolbar options

Comment: The relationships are perfectly correct (except Calendar - Date). The problem here is that "Branch" is not part of the filter context.

Comment: @RADO, calendar and date are related by weekendingdate and date columns, both are dates. Would you please let me know how do i bring branch in the filter context? I need to filter branch and client. Thanks.

Comment: @bmsqldev No sir, that measure also didn't work. It gives the total % of the top 5 clients. I need to show total % value FOR the top 5 clients. Total % is calculated for all the clients.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out ?